# Accessing a website's Local Storage Key/Value Items using VBA and Selenium returns Empty values

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I manually open up the Chrome browser and go to 'https://www.google.com/' and hit F12 to go to developer tools. I then go to Console and type in `localStorage.key(0)` to get the key of the first item in local storage and I get '*whatever*'.

However, when I run the following test code the returned value in firstKey is Empty.

```
Sub GetLocalStorage()

    Dim driverGoogle As Object
    Dim firstKey As Variant
    
    Set driverGoogle = CreateObject("Selenium.Chromedriver")
    
    driverGoogle.Get "https://www.google.com/"
    driverGoogle.Window.SetSize 1800, 1050
    
    firstKey = driverGoogle.ExecuteScript("localStorage.key(0);")

End Sub
```

I even changed `localStorage.key(0)` to incorrect `localStorage.aaakey(0)` make sure `ExecuteScript` was actually executing and sure enough Selenium threw an error.

So, how to get Local Storage key/values?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add delay to let the site loaded.
Currently you are trying to apply `driverGoogle.ExecuteScript("localStorage.key(0);")` script immediately after sending the URL to the web driver while the page just starting loading.

Comment: The site is fully loaded when I step through the code. So I can presume you have run the code and firstKey is not empty?

Comment: Well, if you have time, would you be kind enough to step through this code to see what you get. I may have a local issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have VBA on my machine at all...

Answer (score 0):

The ExecuteScript string needed the 'return' instruction. Once added everything works fine.

`firstKey = driverGoogle.ExecuteScript("return localStorage.key(0);")`